# Which is more performant? Custom SQL or PowerBI joins/manipulation

Tags: mysql, powerbi, tableau-api, powerquery, m

I'm in the process of starting to build a new dashboarding project, and wanted some guidance with respect to some best processes regarding data ingestion into PowerBI. My company uses MySQL for data.

Most common dashboarding software (Tableau and PowerBI, not sure of others) has features to use a GUI to do the equivalent of SQL commands. They also have the option to just do straight custom SQL to get data as well.

Is there a performance advantage to using custom SQL vs the GUI? Does the GUI take advantage of indexing?

Comment: Could this be comprehensively tested in the time it takes to ask the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know as much about Tableau, but with Power BI, most of the GUI transformations are converted to SQL as the "native query" that gets sent back to the server. You can read more about this here:

http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-checking-query-folding-with-view-native-query

Basically, using the Power BI GUI is just as efficient as custom SQL unless it's folding inefficiently or you are doing transformations that can't automatically be folded.

Answer (score 0):

With Tableau, you can write custom SQL yourself, but you get more benefit out of Tableau by modeling the relationships between your tables and views in Tableau, and letting Tableau generate optimized SQL for each specific view. When you use hand-written custom SQL, that removes opportunities for Tableau to generate optimized SQL. For instance, Tableau will only select fields that are used in a visualization. It can cull joins that are unnecessary for the particular visualization, and can fuse similar related queries into a single query.

There are very few cases where you really need to use custom SQL with Tableau, say if you want to call a database specific function, but all the typical things you need to do join, union, filter, select, case, group, aggregate, perform calculations are available without hard coding the SQL. You can think of a Tableau data source as template for many similar queries, and Tableau generates a specific query from that template for just the data needed for the particular visualization.

If you're going to use Tableau, take the time to learn it, rather than just copy your previous SQL in unchanged.